How to delete the GBM (Google Business (former GMB, Google My business) Messages) notifications
In the iOS Google Maps App, Google Business notification never gone away like this.


To remove that notification.

Go to your business using your web browser.
then go to the review section
The URL ends with reviews like this https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%.......46091/customers/reviews.
Change reviews to messages like this https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%.......46091/customers/messages
Now you can access the messages and remove annoying notifications!

This workaround works at the moment (Sep. 25, 2024), but it might be gone because Business Messages is discontinued. Therefore you might want to do this ASAP.
